# Factorization $x^4+px^3+qx^2+r x +s=(x^2+a x +b)(x^2+\bar a x +\bar b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, factoring, quartics

Question:

Under what condition, does the quartic polynomial with rational coefficients
$p$, $q$, $r$ and $s$ factorizes as

$$x^4+px^3+qx^2+r x +s= (x^2+a x +b)(x^2+\bar a x +\bar b) $$

with $a$, $b$ complex numbers, along with their conjugates $\bar a $, $\bar b$.

Examples:

$$x^4+2x^3+6x^2+2x+1=( x^2 +(1-i \sqrt3)x +1) (x^2 +(1+i \sqrt3)x +1) $$
$$x^4+2x^3+4x^2+2=( x^2 +(1+i)x +(1-i)) (x^2 +(1-i)x +(1+i))  $$

Note that the symmetry of coefficients leads to such factorization, as seen in the first example; but not exclusively so, as shown by the second example.

Is there any test on the coefficients $p$, $q$, $r$ and $s$ that can be carried out to determine the possibility of such factorization? I reviewed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) the discriminate tests on the nature of roots for quartic equations and did not find anything applicable.

Comment: Expand the right hand side of your equation using some algebra and equate the polynomial coefficients.

Comment: The quartic should have two pairs of complex roots (which means no real roots).

Comment: @IvanNeretin - Note that $a$, $b$ could be real as a special case.

Comment: Then you have $a=\bar a$, and your quartic is a square of some quadratic. In a way, this can be thought of as an intermediate case between "four distinct roots on the real line" and "four distinct roots outside of the real line".

Comment: You can say your opinion about the answer. (good or bad)

Comment: Do you find my answer helpful?

Comment: @lonestudent - it looks good. I’ll test the conditions on a few cases

Comment: I would like to add your examples to my answer.  I tested them all.  There is no missing / error.  For example, I want to add the test we made to your two equations to the answer.  indeed the $ c = 1 $ rational root theorem works perfectly.By the way, no different answer can be given to your question that would violate the conditions and equation I said..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer:

Actually, the things I do, do not involve any special manipulation. It just contains simple algebra.

Let $a,b,c,d \in\mathbb R$  then we have,

$$\left(x^2+(a+bi)x+(c+di)\right)\left(x^2+(a-bi)x+(c-di)\right)=x^4+2ax^3+(a^2+b^2+2c)x^2+(2ac+2bd)x+(c^2+d^2).$$

$$x^4+px^3+qx^2+rx+s=x^4+2ax^3+(a^2+b^2+2c)x^2+(2ac+2bd)x+(c^2+d^2)$$

which follows

$$\begin{cases} p=2a \\ q=a^2+b^2+2c \\ r=2ac+2bd \\s=c^2+d^2\end{cases} $$

- If $d=0$, then the system of equation becomes extremely simple. I'll leave this case to you.  Here we will work with $d≠0.$
- If $d≠0$, then $s-c^2≠0$. We have,

$$\begin{cases} a=\frac p2 \\b^2+2c=q-\frac{p^2}{4} \\pc+2bd=r \\c^2+d^2=s \end{cases}$$

$$\implies \begin{cases}\left( \frac{r-pc}{2d}\right)^2+2c-q+\frac{p^2}{4} =0 \\ c^2+d^2=s \end{cases}$$

Finally we get,

$$\frac{(r-pc)^2}{4(s-c^2)}+2c-q+\frac{p^2}{4} =0$$

$$\color {gold}{\boxed {\color{black}{8 c^3-4qc^2+(2pr-8s)c+(4qs-sp^2-r^2)=0.}}}$$

As it seems, we obtain the cubic equation with respect to $c$.

If all of the coefficients of the cubic equation are real numbers, then it has at least one real root. Therefore, we can always choose $c$ to be a real number.

If you accept $a,b,c,d$ as rational, then we can immediately use the Rational Root theorem.

For this, all we need is to find the factors of this expression $\color{red}{\dfrac{4qs-sp^2-r^2}{8}.}$

We're almost done.  We have the last two restrictions.

After finding real $c$, then we must check the following two cases:

- $s-c^2≥0$
- $p^2-4q+8c≤0.$

If these conditions hold, then you can easily find the $a,b,d$ from the system of equations.

End of the answer.

Comment: brilliant answer, how so pr0

Comment: Rather than explicitly finding the roots, you could identify, out of the critical points of the boxed equation, which ones satisfy the last two conditions. And then plug each of those values of $c$ (along with the values of $c$ on the boundary) into the cubic and see if there are two outputs with different sign. This way, you wouldn't need to find the roots of a cubic.

Comment: @lone student- in case of three real roots of $c$, would you check all of them?. There should be only one valid. Do you have an example to illustrate?

Comment: @Quanto I guess it's not possible.  Different $ c$ means different $a, b, c, d.$  This is only possible when the roots are replaced.  Can we get such complex numbers again when the roots are replaced?  I have not researched. In your case $c=1$ works. I didn't check other roots. (in your case there are $3$ real roots.)